# How to copy a Stream<String> in dart?

Tags: dart

How do we copy a `Stream<String>` in dart?
How can we loop over

```
Stream<String> blocks(File file) {
    return file.openRead()
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(LineSplitter());
}
```

more than once?

Comment: Copy it... to what?

Comment: I'm not a Dart user, but I'm pretty sure your `blocks` function is incorrect because you aren't closing your file, or does `openRead` return an object that automatically closes the file when after it iterates over the file?

Comment: another Stream<String> because after using ` ``await for(String line in blocks(file))``` you cant loop over it again

Comment: i cant close the sink with openRead

Comment: You don't want to copy into a `Stream` (because a Dart `Stream` does not represent an in-memory collection), you'll want to read it into a `List<String>` instead.

Comment: You can call `.asBroadcastStream()` on a stream in order to subscribe to/loop over more than once.

Comment: @mmcdon20 `asBroadcastStream()` does not allow the `Stream` to be re-iterated over again from the start, it only lets you have multiple subscribers, and pause, resume and cancel the Stream. That's not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Or better yet, why not just call the method again when you need to loop over the file contents the second time? The blocks method would return a completely new stream starting from the beginning every time you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `blocks` each time you need to loop over the data?

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

Future<void> main() async {
  final file = File('<INSERT SOME FILE NAME HERE>');
  await for (String line in blocks(file)) {
    print('stream 1: $line');
  }
  await for (String line in blocks(file)) {
    print('stream 2: $line');
  }
}

Stream<String> blocks(File file) {
  return file.openRead().transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter());
}
```

Comment: Because that would re-open the file from disk and re-read it all over again, which would be slower than just opening it once and storing its data in-memory (and storing data in-memory also allows programs to work with the data using synchronous (i.e. non-`async`) techniques, which are generally faster and simpler).